# WIX 3.7 call WebService in CustomActions

Tags: web-services, wix, windows-installer, custom-action, wix3.7

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and WIX 3.7. I need to call a WebService Method when the Application is Unistall.

Everything is correctly defined in .WXS file. I have the correct webreference int the Project. The problem is that the WebService reference does not ejecuted.

> [CustomAction]
>
> ```
>     public static ActionResult CheckPID(Session session)
>     { 
>        Directory.Delete(@"C:\BBB");//IT IS EJECUTED
>         ServiceClient serviceClient = new ServiceClient();//ERROR
>         Directory.Delete(@"C:\AAA");//IT DOES NOT  EJECUTED
>         return ActionResult.Success;
>     }
> ```

Any idea how can I make a it Works?

Thanks

Comment: Have you logged the installer?  It should contain the stack trace if your code threw an exception.

Comment: Is ServiceClient your class? It will crash if it fails in your ctor, obviously.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, the return error is "MainEngineThread is returning 1605"

Comment: Hi Phil... The ServiceClient is the name of my WebService.. I have setting **using CheckPID.WCFReference;** and then I create an instance of my webservice.